# azure virtual machine size capabilities

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am quite a novice on Azure and I am bit stuck trying to understand virtual machine size and features.

I have just deployed **"Hortonworks Sandbox with HDP 2.4"** virtual machine template on a DS3_v2 machine, which seems to have following features: 4Cores, 14GB Ram, 8 data disks and 28Gb ssds that it is pretty decent to run a proof of concept, however i have some doubts. I am not sure about the total disk size available on this machine if its 200GB or 100GB, does this size include the os vhd? I understand i cant attach till 8 data disk from my storage account sum up either 100GB or 200GB.

DS3_v2 machine also includes Azure premium storage that i think it referes to 28GB ssds, I guess i could have two ssd data disks of 14 GB each?

I really appreciate any insight about these doubts.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your OS disk is a different one, the 28 GB SSD is a local disk and is a temporary disk(think of it as D:\ where your OS is in C:) and the data present on this is not guaranteed during hardware failures. The data on 8 disks you can attach are persisted and you can choose (GRS or RA-GRS Geo Redundant storage) and each of these disks can be upto 1 TB (around 1023 GB) which means you can attach a total of around 8 TB storage data disks to DS3_V2 instance.